# Disable "live log setup" and "live log teardown" in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Is there an option (or combination of options) in `pytest` to view only "live log call" ?

I have to establish a handful of sessions in setup and close them in teardown, so a lot of noise from those logs, (changing them to debug is not going to help me as these logs are printed from another library)

```
------- live log setup ---------
noisy logs
---------- live log call ------------
needed logs
--------- live log teardown ------------
noisy logs
```

Comment: This be done with [caplog]( https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html#caplog-fixture) fixture, we can set the level of those noisy modules using context manager as in the documentation.